# Wordpress place comment checkbox on the same line as the consent text

Tags: wordpress

In the comment section under my posts, the remember be consent (*save my name email and website in this browser for the next time i comment*) is under the checkbox. How can I place them on the same line?

[image]

Comment: Please make a screenshot of your issue and paste the code/link to website, i can't really give an answer w/o having those data

Comment: @Diego I added the screenshot. It's Hungarian, but you see the checkbox and the text beneath.

Comment: Good,that's a step forward. Include your HTML code aswell for that part of page please

Comment: You need to make both checkbox and text `inline`